# MPMoviePlayerController Endless Loading

Tags: iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller

I'm trying to play an MP4 file with the `MPMoviePlayerController` (also tried two m4v files, same problem), and finally got the video player to come up, but it just stays loading. Here's my code, executed on a button press:

```
NSString *videoFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"attn8" ofType:@"mp4" inDirectory:@""];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:videoFile isDirectory:NO];
player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];

player.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
//put on a whim from another answer, made no difference

[self.view addSubview:[player view]];
player.fullscreen = true;
[player prepareToPlay];
[player play];
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with Xcode. Also, tags aren't supposed to be in the title.

Comment: If memory serves me, there is a notification that you can subscribe to that gives you extra information about playback and possibly why playback has stopped.